# Sine Function on Simulink

Tags: frequency, matlab, sine, simulink, function

I'm trying to add the following function on my Simulink model.

[image]

where C, B, and N are already variables in my file. Is the correct way to multiply omega by the gains 3N and N/2 an input that into the sine (as shown)

[image]

or should I change the value of the frequency? If so, what would be the right value?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: This is a tricky question because nothing is specified for what your frequency _should be_. Henceforth, the frequency is **arbitrary**. The only difference you will see is more wave cycles per period of time. It won't affect any magnitudinal behavior... The only thing you'll see is the positional phase value of the wave. The right frequency value is what you need, which isn't specified here, **so just choose something...** :)

Answer (score 1):

It really comes down to how much control you want.
\$f_1(\omega) = Csin(\frac{Nt}{2}\omega)\$

\$f_2(\omega) = Bsin(3Nt \omega)\$

In your two equations the gain (C,B) and frequency (N) are your tunabled.  Your attempt to realize this in simulink is purely on gain which produces:

\$f_1(\omega) = \frac{N}{2}sin(\omega t)\$

\$f_2(\omega) = 3Nsin(\omega t)\$

If you want a sinus source matching these equations then use the *source* block configured appropriately 
[image]

If you want to be able to vary the frequency and/or the amplitude use the SineWave function block. Feed in a ramp to set \$3N\omega\$ and an output gain block to set C

[image]

Your variables:  B,C, N \$\omega\$ can then be set in an m-file or datadictionary.

IF you need these parameters varying this is also viable but a multiplying block is required and the ramp needs a varying slope (maybe via a mux)

Comment: So, the omega is an input form the simulation I'm doing, meaning it varies. And then B, C, and N are on my parameters file. I think the latter option you gave is the one that will fit my model. I appreciate your reply, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Making sinusoidal signal with parameters:

Start from linear ramp block (=t).  Multiply it with wanted angular velocity. It in your case is calculated from your variables. Input the result to sine calculation block. Multiply the result with the wanted amplitude.